# Why do new rails 7.0.2.4 apps come with bin/dev, but rails 7.0.3 apps do not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I noticed a new `Rails 7.0.2.4` app comes with a file called `bin/dev`, whereas a new `Rails 7.0.3` app doesn't appear to come with that file.

I think running `bin/dev` instead of `rails server` precompiles javascripts on for localhost (so it is preferable to rails server when editing javascripts in development), but I don't understand why it's there for some rails versions and not others? I'm sure it would work in tandem with some other pieces of rails machinery, but I'm not sure which pieces.

(sorry, it's a basic question)

Comment: `bin/dev` is to run cssbundling and jsbundling. Its most likely just a matter of changing defaults.

Comment: @max thanks Max. Do you know from what and to what? (or even better, how to find out for myself?) (I sometimes struggle to work out what the app is using, especially since there have been quite a few changes in recent years)

Comment: I think Rails 7 initially just shipped with import-maps as a default.

Answer (score 11):

`cssbundling-rails`, `jsbundling-rails`, and `tailwindcss-rails` all add or modify *bin/dev* and *Procfile.dev* when any of the corresponding install commands are executed:

`bin/rails css:install:[tailwind|bootstrap|bulma|postcss|sass]`
*https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails/blob/v1.1.0/lib/install/install.rb#L53*

`bin/rails javascript:install:[esbuild|rollup|webpack]`
*https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/blob/v1.0.2/lib/install/install.rb#L44*

`bin/rails tailwindcss:install`
*https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/blob/v2.0.8/lib/install/tailwindcss.rb#L51*

When running `rails new` there are two options that add these gems by default and execute their install command:

```sh
-j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT] # Choose JavaScript approach [options: importmap (default), webpack, esbuild, rollup]
                              # Default: importmap
-c, [--css=CSS]               # Choose CSS processor [options: tailwind, bootstrap, bulma, postcss, sass... check https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails]
```

`-j` option will [add](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.3/railties/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb#L319) *jsbundling-rails* (except when *importmap* is specified) and will run this [method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.3/railties/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb#L444):

```rb
def run_javascript
  return if options[:skip_javascript] || !bundle_install?

  case adjusted_javascript_option
  when "importmap"                    then rails_command "importmap:install"

  # NOTE: this command will add `bin/dev`
  when "webpack", "esbuild", "rollup" then rails_command "javascript:install:#{adjusted_javascript_option}"

  end
end
```

`-c` option will [add](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.3/railties/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb#L355) *tailwindcss-rails* or *cssbundling-rails* and will run this [method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.3/railties/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb#L459):

```
def run_css
  return if !options[:css] || !bundle_install?

  if !using_node? && options[:css] == "tailwind"

    # NOTE: this command will add `bin/dev`
    rails_command "tailwindcss:install"

  else

    # NOTE: and this command will add `bin/dev`
    rails_command "css:install:#{options[:css]}"

  end
end
```

---

If `-j` option is omitted rails installs `importmap-rails` by default and it [doesn't add](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/blob/v1.1.0/lib/install/install.rb) *bin/dev* when `bin/rails importmap:install` is executed.

---

Also `bin/dev` just runs  `foreman start -f Procfile.dev`. `foreman` runs multiple commands at the same time. Take a look at *Procfile.dev* to see what commands are being run.

```
css: bin/rails tailwindcss:watch  # added by `tailwindcss-rails`

css: yarn build:css --watch       # added by `cssbundling-rails`

js: yarn build --watch            # added by `jsbundling-rails`
```