# How do I get js: yarn build --watch working in my Procfile.dev in a new rails 7 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created my new rails 7.0.3 project using

```
rails new my_app_name --css tailwind --database=postgresql
```

Noticed JS isn't working when I run bin/dev. To my Procfile.dev I added

```
js: yarn build --watch
```

Got an error saying I was missing a package.json file so I did

```
npm init --yes and npm install
```

Instead I got this error

```
error Command "build" not found.
```

I found this post, but still I haven't been able to figure out how to fix it for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72535848/15885731

From that post, I tried running

```
./bin/bundle add jsbundling-rails
./bin/rails javascript:install:[esbuild|rollup|webpack]
```

But I get this error

```
zsh: bad pattern: javascript:install:[esbuild
zsh: command not found: rollup
zsh: command not found: webpack]
```

The docs for the gem jsbundling-rails says

```
"You can configure your bundler options in the build:css script in package.json or via the installer-generated tailwind.config.js for Tailwind"
```

And I have a tailwind.config.js file, but have no idea what to do with it. It looks like this

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
  ]
}
```

And my package.json created from the earlier command doesn't contain any scripts

```
"scripts": {
},
```

Any ideas how I solve this?

EDIT:
I ended up making a new app "rails new my_app_name --css tailwind --database=postgresql -j esbuild" and it worked perfectly from start.

Comment: This bit of code : `rails javascript:install:[esbuild|rollup|webpack]` means you have to choose your javascript bundling method between, esbuild, rollup, webpack. You cannot copy the whole array `[esbuild|rollup|webpack]`. Also I would like to help but even for an experienced programmer, the setup is not very easy sometimes. Also you know how Procfile work ? You basically need a gem called "Foreman" and boot Foreman like this : `foreman start -f Procfile.dev`or `foreman start -f Procfile` depending how many procfiles you have. Then Foreman will start a process for every line in the procfile

Comment: Maybe create a new app adding the javascript bundling method in your ogirinal command: `rails new my_app_name --css tailwind --database=postgresql -j esbuild` it should create a proper app with Tailwind and esbuild. The Procfile should be all set properly. Also make your you have recent versions of NPM, Yarn and NodeJs installed on your computer.

Comment: I tried running all 3 javascript:install options, but didnt work. Instead I ended up making a new app rails new my_app_name --css tailwind --database=postgresql -j esbuild and it works perfectly from start.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this to `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
    "type": "module",
    "build": "yarn build:css && yarn build:js",
    "build:css": "yarn build:css:application",
    "build:css:application": "tailwindcss -i app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o app/assets/builds/application.css -c config/tailwind.config.js --postcss postcss.config.js --minify",
    "build:js": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --loader:.png=binary --loader:.svg=binary",
    "failure:js": "rm ./app/assets/builds/application.js && rm ./app/assets/builds/application.js.map",
    "dev": "tsc-watch --noClear -p tsconfig.json --onSuccess \"yarn build:js\" --onFailure \"yarn failure:js\""
  }
```

Works for me.