# Ruby on rails bin/dev: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

im trying to learn ruby on rails from example here:
https://blog.dennisokeeffe.com/blog/2022-02-19-rails-7-using-react-with-esbuild
And i got a problem with bin/dev command. It says that there is

```
$ bin/dev
/c/Users/btome/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/foreman: line 6: /c/Users/btme/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/ruby: No such file or directory
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdKuW.png)

i was watching others tutorials and in every they are using bin/dev which is not working for me.

Like i understand that bin/dev is starting some kind of "watch"? which

```
rails s
```

does not.

My dev file look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if ! gem list foreman -i --silent; then
  echo "Installing foreman..."
  gem install foreman
fi

exec foreman start -f Procfile.dev "$@"
```

```
$ which ruby
/c/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby
```

After i edited dev file:

```
#!/c/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby

if ! gem list foreman -i --silent; then
  echo "Installing foreman..."
  gem install foreman
fi

exec foreman start -f Procfile.dev "$@"
```

I got this message:

```
$ bin/dev
bin/dev: --> bin/dev
Unmatched keyword, missing `end' ?
> 3  if ! gem list foreman -i --silent; then
> 6  fi
> 8  exec foreman start -f Procfile.dev "$@"
bin/dev:3: syntax error, unexpected unary-, expecting `do' or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
if ! gem list foreman -i --silent; then
                         ^
bin/dev:8: syntax error, unexpected constant, expecting `do' or '{' or '('
exec foreman start -f Procfile.dev "$@"
                      ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72531796/2483313

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you copy/paste an error it's better to copy too much than not enough. The screenshot of your error _looks like_ what's missing is actually `/a/long/path/to/ruby` - which is THE crucial part of your problem. Can you confirm that (check if that path to ruby exists) and then edit your question to include those pertinent details. (until then, voted to close)