# Rails "bin/dev" and "rails server"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to ask what are the core differences of running the two commands as both of then starts the web server locally.

I was struggled to make bootstrap 5 to work on my app, my app didn't find the bootstrap thus couldn't use any classes or components of bootstrap. After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71216446/bootstrap-5-1-not-working-in-jsbundling-rails-7/72553402?noredirect=1#comment137413555_72553402), I change the command from "rails s" to ".bin/dev" and everything worked. Now I understand that "./bin/dev" refreshes js/css files (also mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72531796/why-do-new-rails-7-0-2-4-apps-come-with-bin-dev-but-rails-7-0-3-apps-do-not)), is this the only reason I should use "./bin/dev" instead of "rails server"? I would like to know more about what's actually happening when you run the two commands.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a rails app with esbuild and bootstrap, this is what happens when you run `bin/dev`:

```bash
bin/dev
|
`-> foreman start -f Procfile.dev
    |
    `-> bin/rails server
    |
    `-> yarn build --watch
    |   `-> node_modules/.bin/esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets --watch
    |
    `-> yarn build:css --watch
        `-> node_modules/.bin/sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules --watch
```

You can see what commands you have configured to [run](https://ddollar.github.io/foreman/#RUNNING) in `Procfile.dev`:

```rb
# Procfile.dev

web: unset PORT && bin/rails s
js: yarn build --watch
css: yarn build:css --watch
```

Yarn will run your commands from `package.json`:

```js
// package.json

...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets",
    "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
  }
}
```

Notice that compiled js and css are saved into `app/assets/builds` which is where rails will look for your assets, if you never run `bin/dev` that directory would be empty and you will get errors about missing assets or your assets will not update when you make any changes.

> Now I understand that "./bin/dev" refreshes js/css files ..., is this the only reason I should use "./bin/dev" instead of "rails server"

If js and css is the only thing you have in your `Procfile.dev` then yes, you could run `bin/rails server` by itself if you're not working on any frontend assets (you could run all those commands separately if you want).

In case it's not clear, `bin/dev` is for development only. In production, your assets are precompiled only once, there is no need to watch for changes. If you add other commands to `Procfile.dev` then you should probably already know what to do with them in production.

Answer (score 0):

bin/dev is just a ruby script file In Rails app, by default it is being used to run foreman which helps to manage Procfile based application.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if gem list --no-installed --exact --silent foreman; then
  echo "Installing foreman..."
  gem install foreman
fi

# Default to port 3000 if not specified
export PORT="${PORT:-3000}"

exec foreman start -f Procfile.dev "$@"
```

But you can configure it however you want to run the required servers like redis and other bundling things which are required for rails server.

It is an another way to run multiple servers like rails, redis, Sidekiq and yarn at once instead of running them in separate tabs.

rails server command is one of the commands to be part of this bin/dev script.

There is no other difference than this in my point of view.